# Odd format of Message Authentication Code output

Tags: java, security, utf-8, format

I'm running an example from an IBM tutorial which has a simple example to generate a MAC on given plain text. The code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //
    // check args and get plaintext
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.err
                .println("Usage: java MessageAuthenticationCodeExample text");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    byte[] plainText = args[0].getBytes("UTF8");
    //
    // get a key for the HmacMD5 algorithm
    System.out.println("\nStart generating key");
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacMD5");
    SecretKey MD5key = keyGen.generateKey();
    System.out.println("Finish generating key");
    //
    // get a MAC object and update it with the plaintext
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");
    mac.init(MD5key);
    mac.update(plainText);
    //
    // print out the provider used and the MAC
    System.out.println("\n" + mac.getProvider().getInfo());
    System.out.println("\nMAC: ");
    System.out.println(new String(mac.doFinal(), "UTF8"));
}
```

That's all good but running it with the String arg "This is a test" I get the following output:

[image]

In the actual tutorial the MAC output is formatted much more nicely as e.g.

```
 MAC:
Dkdj47x4#.@kd#n8a-x>
```

, by nicely I mean characters that I actually recognize!

I thought the use of "UTF8" parameter served this purpose but I have probably got it wrong so can anyone tell me how I get the output to format like above?

Answer (score 0):

The output of a MAC is an array of bytes. It is no UTF-8 sequence of characters which you could convert into string in a meaningful way. If you want to get something readable out of it, some options are:

- hexadecimal encoding
- base64 encoding

For the purpose of a quick and dirty example you could probably use

```
new String(mac.doFinal(), "ISO-8859-1")
```

You'll probably get something more or less readable. However, if you are unlucky, your mac will contain control characters that will interfere with your output.